# Can "this", "that" and their plurals be used as substantive adjectives in formal writing?

Tags: adjectives, this-that

For example:

> Stein’s avant-garde collection challenges the reader to think of
>   ordinary, everyday objects and concepts in ways that they hadn’t
>   before. **This** is in direct contrast to...

I was told that in this case, "this" should be followed by a noun, as it is an adjective. I know that "this" can be substantive, but is that just informally, or is it acceptable in formal writing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were misinformed. Almost all of what most contemporary students call “determiners” (a class distinct from “adjective”) may be employed as pronouns with propriety in any register, formal or casual: *this*, *that*, *each*, *every*, *some*, quantifiers like *some*, *few*, *many*, and their comparatives (*more*, *less*) and superlatives (*most*, *fewest*), ordinal numbers, and possessives. The only ones I can think of offhand which cannot be employed this way are the articles and *every*.

Indeed there is a burgeoning school of thought which holds that these words should be reclassified as pronouns.

Comment: This is interesting to know, and sounds reasonable to me.  What I don't understand in the OP's question is what _This_ refers to--maybe the whole sentence?

Comment: @Xanne Exactly.